# Form Validation - Add/Remove Jquery Dynamically Added Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm working with some form validation. 
I run the validation on a .blur event for each input.

During each validation, I create a validation summary at the top of the page, listing out all of the errors.This is currently working, with the exception that I can not clear errors from the list.

My question, how can I remove the errors list on each .blue event.
I've added a comment where I've tried to clear the error list.

My Code:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#EditPhone input").blur(function () {
                var a =  $(this).parent();
                var b = a.find(".k-tooltip").text();
                $(".validation-summary-errors ul").html(""); // This does not work
                    $(".k-tooltip").each(function () {
                     var c = $(this).text();
                        $(".validation-summary-errors").show();
                        $(".validation-summary-errors ul").append("<li>" + c + "</li>");
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="validation-summary-errors" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method for example:

```
$(".validation-summary-errors ul").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method for example:

```
 $(".validation-summary-errors ul li").remove();
```